# django - bootstrap datetimepicker is showing todays date in the text box always

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

The problem is that even if I change the value and save the form, when I have to reload the form or enter the page another time, the textbox doesn't show the value I saved, but the today's date.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676039/how-to-stop-datetimepicker-setting-todays-date-in-textbox-by-default-onclick) that the answer is to change `useCurrent` to false, but this doesn't solve my problem.

I'm developing with Django 2.1 and postgreSQL, but I think in this case it doesn't have any relation to the problem because if I delete the class `datetimepicker` from the input, the date shows correctly.

My actual JS:

```
var endDateMin = new Date();

endDateMin.setDate(endDateMin.getDate() + 1);

$(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
        {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm',
            minDate: endDateMin,
            useCurrent: false,
            icons: {
                time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                date: "fa fa-calendar",
                up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
                previous: "fa fa-arrow-left",
                next: "fa fa-arrow-right",
            }
        }
    );
});
```

My form: (the field is end_date)

```
class UpdateProjectGeneralForm(forms.ModelForm):
    end_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',])

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', 'short_description', 'category', 'investment', 'description',
                  'end_date', 'image')
        widgets = {
            'description': SummernoteWidget(attrs={'summernote': {
                'placeholder': 'Describe your project here...'}}),
            'image': FileInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(UpdateProjectGeneralForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # there's a `fields` property now
        self.fields['investment'].required = True
        self.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'enter the project name here...'})
        self.fields['short_description'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': '2',
                   'maxlength': '135',
                   'class': 'textarea-limited',
                   'placeholder': 'enter a short description of your project limited to 135 characters'})
        self.fields['end_date'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datetimepicker'
        #if self.fields['end_date']:
            # self.fields['end_date'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = self.fields['end_date']
        #else:
        self.fields['end_date'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        self.fields['category'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'selectpicker'
        self.fields['category'].widget.attrs['data-live-search'] = 'true'
        self.fields['category'].widget.attrs['data-size'] = '5'
        self.fields['image'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'btn btn-outline-default btn-file btn-round'
        # evade all labels and help text to appear when using "as_crispy_tag"
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper._help_text_inline = True
```

View:

```
class ProjectEditGeneralView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'webplatform/project_edit_general.html'
    model = Project
    form_class = UpdateProjectGeneralForm
    success_message = 'Project successfully updated!'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project-edit-general', args=(self.object.id,))

    # Make the view only available for the users with current fields
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        project = self.get_object()
        # here you can make your custom validation for any particular user
        if request.user != project.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Set field as current user
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.history_change_reason = 'Project Updated'
        return super(ProjectEditGeneralView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The field on Model:

```
end_date = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Select the end date of your project.'
        ),
    )
```

Comment: How are you storing and retrieving the saved date?

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I updated the question with all the relative information.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie sorry but the ping, but do you have any idea about it?

Comment: well, the model form + the update view should do this by default. in fact, if I doesn't use DateTimePicker (js), it shows the retrieved information. And, It seems that the problem is that this JS updates my field deleting the current value, because if I update the page, I can see for an instant the current date. edit: Here is a gif of the field with the page being updated few times: https://gyazo.com/175c1b4d9b81f6ffe6e95b97e32b23ef

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample Django application with [Bootstrap-DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to try to reproduce your issue.

In my `forms.py`, I added `end_date` to the `widgets` dictionary. So, in your example, your `widgets` dictionary might look something like:

```
widgets = {
            'description': SummernoteWidget(attrs={'summernote': {
                'placeholder': 'Describe your project here...'}}),
            'image': FileInput(),
            'end_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'datetimepicker'})
        }
```

Then I read that the datetimepicker uses MomentJS, and in MomentJS, `HH` corresponds to 24 hour time and `hh` corresponds to 12 hour time. In your Python time string, you're using 24 hour time, so you probably want your datetimepicker's `format` to use `HH` instead of `hh`:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
        {
            ...
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            ...
        }
);
```

I read a few other posts where users had issues with the date/time formatting because the format they were using on the JS-side was different from what they were using on the Python-side, so definitely make sure those are the same. Using this format, I was able to get the datetimepicker to show the correct date and time.

If you make these changes, do you still have the same issue?

Comment: It seems that my project is using AM/PM, because when I try this, it throws me an error saying that the format is not the correct one.